# Extending expiration date of trustedCertEntry within a keystore

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, private-key, truststore

Using keytool, I am trying to extend the expiration date of a trustedCertEntry within a keystore that I have. The keystore has the contents below

```
$ keytool -list -keystore certs/authTruststore.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

sts, Nov 11, 2013, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 8D:33:B7:69:DE:75:8F:22:E2:95:2C:EB:93:65:41:31:42:A6:E3:A7
__
localhost, Nov 11, 2013, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): F4:A9:84:1E:7F:BF:5D:71:58:74:E4:C6:00:49:37:49:38:3E:31:BE
__    
security_localhost, Nov 11, 2013, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 6B:F8:E1:36:EB:36:D4:A5:6E:A0:5C:7A:E4:B9:A4:5B:63:BF:97:5D
```

I can successfully modify the expiration date of the second entry, localhost of type PrivateKeyEntry but when attempting to modify the expirations of the other two with the same command I get the following error:

```
$ keytool -selfcert -v -alias security_localhost -validity 3650 -keystore certs/authTruststore.jks -storepass ****

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <localhost> has no key
java.lang.Exception: Alias <localhost> has no key
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.recoverKey(KeyTool.java:3095)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doSelfCert(KeyTool.java:2442)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:1071)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
```

How can I go about extending these expiration dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html#selfcertCmd). It says,

```
Generates an X.509 v1 self-signed certificate, using keystore information including
the private key and public key associated with alias
```

So you can update a certificate using **-selfcert** that are associated with a key. Your `first` and `third` are trusted certificate entries, where as your `second` entry is a PrivateKeyEntry. The certificate for this entry is associated with its `PrivateKey`. Where as the other 2 are not.

If those 2 certificates are expired you can only update them with the latest in the same way you added them to the keystore in the first place. By doing **-importcert**.

Note: `-selfcert` is now obsolete. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).

Comment: Can you please post the command you used to extend the validity of the certificate of type "trustedCertEntry" ? Or can you post the steps needed to do so ?

Comment: keytool -importcert -keystore YOUR_KEYSTORE -storepass PASSWORD -alias ALIAS -file NEW_CERT_FILE